# ¿Cómo hacer un formulario que llame a funciones en PHP?

Tags: php, html, select

¡Hola Buenas! Necesito hacer un formulario en HTML el cual llame a unas funciones que tengo predefinidas en PHP. He probado con esto:

```
<form method="post">
<select name="menu">
    <option value="1">Inserción</option>
    <option value="2">Burbuja</option>
</select>
```

Y para seleccionar los datos tengo:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$seleccionado = $_POST['menu'];
echo $seleccionado;
}
```

¿Alguna idea? Gracias :)

Comment: Para llamar al php tienes que asignarle al form la pagina php que recibira los datos,  `<form method="post" action="TuPagina.php">`

Comment: tienes un servidor apache + php instalado?

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente debes agregar un `action` a tu `form` y obviamente agregar un botón de tipo `submit`:

**NOTA:** el valor que colocas en el atributo `action` es la ruta del archivo php que va a recibir los datos.

```
<form method="post" action="paginaAEjecutar.php">
    <select name="menu">
        <option value="1">Inserción</option>
        <option value="2">Burbuja</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Eso es todo !